# How to define an xor operator in Io

Tags: xor, iolanguage

I'm working through Chapter 3, Day to of [Seven Languages in Seven Weeks](https://pragprog.com/book/btlang/seven-languages-in-seven-weeks) ("The Sausage King"). I've copied the code straight out of the book, but it's not working.

```
Io 20110905
```

Add a new operator to the OperatorTable.

```
Io> OperatorTable addOperator("xor", 11)
==> OperatorTable_0x336040:
Operators
  0   ? @ @@
  1   **
  2   % * /
  3   + -
  4   << >>
  5   < <= > >=
  6   != ==
  7   &
  8   ^
  9   |
  10  && and
  11  or xor ||
  12  ..
  13  %= &= *= += -= /= <<= >>= ^= |=
  14  return

Assign Operators
  ::= newSlot
  :=  setSlot
  =   updateSlot

To add a new operator: OperatorTable addOperator("+", 4) and implement the + message.
To add a new assign operator: OperatorTable addAssignOperator("=", "updateSlot") and implement the updateSlot message.
```

The output confirms that it was added in slot 11. Now let's make sure true doesn't already have an xor method defined.

```
Io> true slotNames
==> list(not, asString, asSimpleString, type, else, ifFalse, ifTrue, then, or, elseif, clone, justSerialized)
```

It does not. So let's create it.

```
Io> true xor := method(bool if(bool, false, true))
==> method(
    bool if(bool, false, true)
)
```

And one for false as well.

```
Io> false xor := method(bool if(bool, true, false))
==> method(
    bool if(bool, true, false)
)
```

Now check that the xor operator was added.

```
Io> true slotNames
==> list(not, asString, asSimpleString, type, else, xor, ifFalse, ifTrue, then, or, elseif, clone, justSerialized)
```

Great. Can we use it? (Again, this code is straight from the book.)

```
Io> true xor true

  Exception: true does not respond to 'bool'
  ---------
  true bool                            Command Line 1
  true xor                             Command Line 1
```

No. And I'm not sure what "does not respond to 'bool'" means.

Comment: What is this `bool` thing you are using there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've forgot the comma and defined a parameterless method whose first message is `bool` - which `true` (on which it is called) does not know anything to do with. What you wanted to do was

```
true xor := method(bool, if(bool, false, true))
//                     ^
// or much simpler:
false xor := true xor := method(bool, self != bool)
// or maybe even
false xor := true xor := getSlot("!=")
// or, so that it works on all values:
Object xor := getSlot("!=")
```

Comment: Thanks for a great answer that goes beyond pointing out the typo and teaches me a couple of things!